# Passing a list of filenames to SwiftLint using awk and xargs

Tags: awk, xargs, swiftlint

#### Goal

I'm trying to introduce SwiftLint to an existing project, in a gradual way, enforcing a *"you touched it, you fix it"* rule. All changes to the project are done via branches and PRs and the intention is that all files created or modified by a PR must pass the linting rules before being merged.

#### Progress

Currently I have:

```
git diff --name-status "main" \
    | grep '^[^D]' \
    | grep '.swift$' \
    | awk -F '\t' '{ printf("%s\0", $NF) }' \
    | xargs -0 swiftlint lint --strict --quiet --reporter xcode
```

Which is:

- All changes relative to "main"
- .. that aren't deletions
- .. that are to `.swift` files
- .. extract the last tab-separated field (to handle renames), listed with `null` separators
- .. and pass to `swiftlint` via `xargs`, expecting `null` separators

That works as intended in an interactive shell, but when invoked by Xcode as a build step it lints every file instead. If I change the last line to include `echo` and then inspect Xcode's build log:

```
    | xargs -0 echo swiftlint lint --strict --quiet --reporter Xcode
```

... I can see that the file names are concatenated together, rather than listed individually.

Expected:

```
swiftlint lint --strict --quiet --reporter Xcode path/to/first.swift path/to/second.swift
```

Actual:

```
swiftlint lint --strict --quiet --reporter Xcode path/to/first.swiftpath/to/second.swift
```

`swiftLint` sees that as one file that doesn't exist and then falls back to linting everything instead.

The outcome is the same whether Xcode is using `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`.

I suspect my problem is around the quoting or escaping of the `\0` for `awk`, but can't find the solution.

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. `grep '^[^D]' | grep '.swift$' | awk -F '\t' '{ printf("%s\0", $NF) }'` = `awk -F '\t' '/^[^D]/ && /.swift$/{ printf("%s\0", $NF) }'`.

Comment: Combining the two `grep`s was on my todo list, but eliminating them both is even better. This `awk` novice thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it looks like that `\0` in `awk`'s `printf()` may not be doing what you want it to (while also likely depending on the platform i.e. Linux or macos)

I'd suggest using `%c` instead as:

```shell
    | awk -F '\t' '{ printf("%s%c", $NF, 0) }' \
```

Appreciate if you can confirm it worked for you, thanks!